# Improve stability of Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility Client

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn, cisco

I'm using Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility Client version 4.8.01090  on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

The VPN works fine for about 10 minutes at a time, at which point the connection drops and the client takes about the same amount of time to reconnect. This happens irrespective from the network I'm using (e.g. at home, in a hotel, etc.).
While I'm able to "fix" it fast by turning the Wifi [off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0), at which point the client quickly reconnects, it is very annoying because whatever I was doing at the time gets interrupted (e.g. video calls).

**Question: How can I improve the performance of Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility Client, so that it
a) doesn't drop connection all the time and
b) doesn't require long time or me fiddling with the Wifi to re-establsh connection?**

Comment: 2 points: 1) What's your MTU (`ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'` or `ip link`. 2) Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  You may click on any of these [edit] links to [edit] your question.

Comment: Have you proven that your wifi doesn't drop every "about 10 minutes at a time" without the VPN up? or that the other end of the VPN isn't dropping? Does the same thing happen on a wired connection(if available)? I have no problems with Cisco Anyconnect on ubuntu 18/20... I WISH it would drop instead of leaving me connected to my job when I forget to turn it off. As a point of reference to waltinator's idea, my mtu is 1500 on the interface and 1300 on the tunnel.